# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: spring, hibernate, list, arraylist

I am trying to access list of friends of given username using hibernate. Here is my Service class in which fetchListOfFriends function is used to convert the generic list to an Arraylist of type of FriendsDetails.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DetailsServiceImpl implements DetailsService {
@Autowired
private DetailsDao detailsDao;
@Override
public List<FriendsDetails> fetchListOfFriends(String name) {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List listOfFriends=detailsDao.fetchListOfFriends(name);
    List<FriendsDetails> friendList= fetchListOfFriendss(listOfFriends);
    if(listOfFriends==null){
        System.out.println("Empty and null list");

    }
    System.out.println("size of friendList" + listOfFriends.size());
    return friendList;
}
private List<FriendsDetails> fetchListOfFriendss(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List genericList) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> result = (List<Object>) genericList; 
    Iterator<Object> itr = result.iterator();
    List<FriendsDetails> listOfFriend= new ArrayList<FriendsDetails>();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
       Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
       System.out.println(obj.toString());
       String userName = String.valueOf(obj[0]); 

       FriendsDetails obj1= new FriendsDetails();
       obj1.setFriendName(userName);

       listOfFriend.add(obj1);
    }
    return listOfFriend;
}
```

DetailsDaoImpl.java

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override

 public List fetchListOfFriends(String name) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String queryToFetchFriends="Select name,presenceStatus from UserPresence where name in (Select friendName from Friends where name='"+name+"')";
    List listOfFriends=session.createSQLQuery(queryToFetchFriends).list();
    return listOfFriends;
}
```

Logs.txt

```
May 22, 2016 1:24:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springmvc] in context with path        [/Testing] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to     [Ljava.lang.Object;] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
at com.tcs.Service.FriendServiceImpl.searchFriend(FriendServiceImpl.java:61)
at com.tcs.Service.FriendServiceImpl.searchFriend(FriendServiceImpl.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does the line `System.out.println(obj.toString());` print in console?

Comment: which method is throwing the exception, and what line is causing the ClassCastException?

Comment: @chsdk No, it is not able to print anything.. till creating a new list 'listOfFriend' the code is executing.. inside while loop there is some error...

Comment: @alexanderific 2nd method.. while loop is not able to run

Comment: Do you not have a stack trace that shows exactly what line is causing the exception? I am betting that the loop is being entered, and one of the first 3 lines of the loop are having problems. What is genericList supposed to be?

Comment: It seems the genericList is a List<String>, possibly this is the line that throws the exception `Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();`. The next() is returning a String and you can not cast a String to a Object[].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to \[Ljava.lang.Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777334/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-ljava-lang-obj)

Comment: Please, add this method `detailsDao.fetchListOfFriends(name)` and a full stack trace.

Comment: @v.ladynev edited my question

Comment: According to the stacktrace, the problem is probably in `FriendServiceImpl` on line 61.

Comment: @PsychoPunch   Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next(); this line is creating issue

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work correctly.

The problem, obviously, that `List listOfFriends` is `List<String>`, not `List<Object[]>`. It is strange, because of `Select name,presenceStatus from UserPresence` should return  `List<Object[]>`.

Maybe Spring set an incorrect implementation of `@Autowired
private DetailsDao detailsDao;`.

Try this code. This should work for `List<String>`

```
private List<FriendsDetails> fetchListOfFriendss(List<?> genericList) {
            Iterator<?> itr = genericList.iterator();
            List<FriendsDetails> listOfFriend = new ArrayList<FriendsDetails>();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Object obj = itr.next();
                String userName = String.valueOf(obj);
                System.out.println(userName);

                FriendsDetails obj1 = new FriendsDetails();
                obj1.setFriendName(userName);

                listOfFriend.add(obj1);
            }
            return listOfFriend;
}
```